# Как правильно проверять поле ввода?

Tags: android, java, android-studio

Например, у нас есть форма, состоящая из логина и пароля, и две кнопки, проверить и очистить. Как правильно будет проверить форму ввода, ввел ли пользователь логин и пароль? Пробую так, только и выскакивает Тоаст сообщение. В чем моя ошибка?

```
public void onClick(View v){
    if(v == btnCheck){
        if((vPass.length() == 0) && (vLog.length() == 0)){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Заполните все поля!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else if(???????????) {
            vPass.setText(txtPassword.getText());
            vLog.setText(txtLogin.getText());
        }
    } else if(v == btnClean){
        txtPassword.setText("");
        vPass.setText("");
        txtLogin.setText("");
        vLog.setText("");
        txtLogin.requestFocus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, вопрос. Что именно не так ? Если выводится ошибка, то опубликуйте сообщения из LogCat.

Comment: @web_alex, ошибки нет, ниже @ЮрийСПб, написал, как правильно проверять условия. )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас, судя по всему, **vPass** и **vLog**  - экземпляры EditText. Не очень понятно, что вы ожидаете получить, вызывая

> vPass.length() == 0

Если вы хотите узнать длину введённой в форму строки, то, очевидно, надо делать так:

```
vPass.getText().length();
```

Далее проверяйте, что вам надо. Например:

```
if((vPass.getText().length()==0) && (vLog.getText().length()==0))
{
//оба поля пусты
}
else if((vPass.getText().length()!=0) && (vLog.getText().length()==0))
{
//пароль введён, а логин нет
}
else if ((vPass.getText().length()==0) && (vLog.getText().length()!=0))
{
//логин введён, а пароль нет
}
else if((vPass.getText().length()!=0) && (vLog.getText().length()!=0))
{
//и пароль и логин введены
//надо как-то их проверить на верность (тут сами делаете так как вам нужно)
}
else
{
//что-то ужасное случилось и вы попали сюда. Такого не должно быть!!!11адын
}
```

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, спасибо)))

Comment: @Verteletsky, you are wellcome)